# Java filter cannot return boolean

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I'm trying to make a filter that filters for distinct objects with the same 2 properties.

I know there are other ways to do this with distinct but I would like to do it with a filter inside a filter. I have following code:

```
filteredOrderLines.stream().filter(o -> filteredOrderLines.stream().filter(o2 -> o.getOrderId().equals(o2.getOrderId()) && o.getProductId().equals(o2.getProductId()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm getting:

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: Stream<OrderLineDTO> cannot be converted to boolean
```

Comment: `filteredOrderLines.stream().filter(o -> filteredOrderLines.stream()` you passed the collection in the stream where you need to filter.

Comment: isn't the message self explanatory to some extent `Stream<OrderLineDTO> cannot be converted to boolean`?

Answer (score 0):

More correct way to solve this task is to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods inside your `Order` class (include both `orderId` and `productId` fields) and call `distinct()` method on your stream. Stream chain will look like this:

```
List<Order> uniqueOrders = filteredOrderLines.stream()
       .distinct()
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And event more correct solution - use `HashSet` to remove duplicates from your initial list.